# What do I do to output a random string in my javascript array every time the page reloads?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a page that when you reload it generates a random question. Here is my code so far:

```js
function questions() {
  var question = ["What's You name?", "What's your age?", "Do you like pizza?"];
  var randomQuestion = truth[Math.floor(idea.length * Math.random())];
  document.getElementById('outputQ').innerHTML = randomQuestion;
}
```

What HTML do I need to add in order to allow it to generate a random question every time the page is reloaded. I would like the output to be in a paragraph tag so I can add CSS classes.

Comment: You would probably just need to call your questions function on page load. At a quick glance, nothing appears to be wrong with this code.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Didn't look hard enough. It's giving me an unexpected token error when I try running it.

Comment: how do i do that (I am fairly new to javascript) @JonathanKuhn

Comment: Where is `truth` defined?

Comment: @TyQ. Did you try running it without the script tags? Those aren't valid in actual javascript, just html.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Just suggested an edit. Yeah, just realized. He had it set to run in JavaScript and not HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
(function questions() {
  var question = ["Whats You name?", "Whats your age?", "Do you like pizza?"];
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  document.getElementById('outputQ').innerHTML = question[i];
})();
```

```html
<p id='outputQ'></p>
```

Comment: You could also do a localStorage or sessionStorage or something of that sort to prevent it from asking the same question it did last time.

Comment: @TyQ. That's cool idea :) But seems like OP didn't ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var getAQuestion = function () {
  var questions = [
    "What's You name?",
    "What's your age?",
    "Do you like pizza?"
  ];
  return questions[Math.round(Math.random()*(questions.length-1))];
};
var question = getAQuestion(); console.log(question);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get one random question, when you generate a number between 0 and 2 (in an array with three entries). A random integer number between 0 and n is generated by`Math.floor(Math.random() * (n + 1));`

So you need to calculate in your case

`var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);`

You get the random entry out of the array with

```
question[i]
```